Comparison operators not functioning properly in SQL
I'm trying to find entries in a table with a "value" greater than 100 million (100,000,000), but my query is returning values that don't fit that criterium. Is there something I'm missing? Shown below is my query and some of the returned values.
SELECT *
FROM cheese_production cp
WHERE cp.Value > 100000000
ORDER BY Value ASC;

10004000 |
10018000 |
10020000 |
10021000 |
10027000 |
10028000 |
100323000 |
10033000 |
100394000 |
10044000 |
100394000 |

Ideally, it would've only returned the following values:
100323000 |
100394000 |
100394000 |


What type does the column have?

It's a "VARCHAR" data type. Is there a way that I can manually change it to "INTEGER"?

Why do you store numbers in a varchar column? If this column contains numbers only, change its datatype. If not, what are the not numeric values? Try to use two different columns then, one for the numbers, one for the rest.

Strings (like varchar) sort differently than numbers. Just like AAB comes after AA, "1001" comes after "100". So does "2".
If you want to sort them like numbers, cast them to integer.
SELECT *
FROM cheese_production cp
WHERE cast(cp.Value as integer) > 1000
ORDER BY Value ASC;

Demonstration
